# How is this checkmate ... or does chess.com have a bug?

Tags: checkmate, online-chess, chess.com

Playing as black against the chess.com computer, the following position was reached and chess.com declared checkmate in its favor. However, I don't see that the black king is in check. So is this a bug?

```
[FEN "2r2r2/p6k/2b1p1R1/2pp2Qp/P2P4/1PN5/1K6/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

There was no time limit in effect and this is the final position. There was a message that said "Checkmate" and I couldn't make any more moves. (White's last move was Qg5; it had been on h4.)

Comment: Can you link the game ? Without the game link it feels unconclusive

Comment: Or maybe a screenshot of the actual chess.com interface could help as well.

Comment: Does it matter? It was game over.

Comment: @Isac: It seems chess.com doesn't provide a link; it certainly didn't save the game so I could refer back to it. I believe that's the case whenever you play a game against the computer.

Comment: @itub: I tried to capture one, but my software wasn't cooperating; thus the PGN diagram.

Comment: @SmallChess: Do you want to play using software that finds checkmates when one isn't there?

Comment: @GreenMatt It would have been forced mate anyway.

Comment: @SmallChess: I get that and did at the time. As Evargalo's answer said, the computer **could** have checkmated on that move. However, if the system is so buggy that it says there is checkmate when there isn't one, I don't want to use it, and wouldn't think others would either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Obviously, this is not a checkmate. Something else must have happened. 
Here is what I could imagine:

- Maybe you have lost on time, and not by checkmate
- Maybe this is the position before White's last move (Qh6# or Qxh5#), which was played a mili-second before the computer claimed victory - so that the mating position wouldn't have been visible on your screen for long enough for you to notice.
- Maybe (but unlikely) there is some bug in the software. Possibly the software 'played' Qh4xh5# but somehow sent Qh4-g5 to the virtual board for unknown reason.

Comment: Neither of the first two suggestions apply; I've updated the question.

Comment: @GreenMatt the third one looks to me like what actually happened